# What's the difference in using prepositions of place?

Tags: prepositions

I've faced with two confusing examples in my English course:

> Notice at the restaurant: "Dogs must not be taken to the restaurant"

and

> Notice in a picture gallery: "Cameras, sticks and umbrellas must be
>   left at the desk"

And I can't understand why they used two different prepositions of a place. In both examples, we speak about some kind of place, not some building so we should use 'at' preposition as in the first one.

Can you explain please the main reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is incorrect. It should be "**into** the restaurant".

The preposition **into** denotes the idea of "ingress" or "entering".

The preposition **at** in your example denotes the idea of "specific location", such as "at the intersection of Broad Street and Main Street".

So even though a place is involved in both, one sentence involves movement with respect to a place, and the other involves specifying a location.